# Formula explanation

Tags: c#, formula

this is my first post here so it might be stuff I did wrong with this post.

I'm a rookie and I hope someone can please explain what these formulas do in a precise way.
I have successfully used it but I don't really understand it.

```
string[] split = new string[str.Length / 2 + (str.Length % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
split[x] = str.Substring(x * 2, x * 2 + 2 > str.Length ? 1 : 2);
```

I have search alot but can't find anything that I could really relate to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a little more code? What is `str` and what is `x` in this case?

Comment: Sorry for not providing more code. Didn't knew that it would do more understanding since I just wanted to know more about the formula and not how it was relative to the rest of my code. But now I know. I got the answer below. Thanks anyway for quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `str` has a content value like `stackoverflow`

```
str.Length -> will be length of the above value i.e. 13

% is called Mod
```

like if you divided the string length(13) divide by 2 gives you balance of either `0` or `1` in this case it won't be `0`.

```
% 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)
```

this is a ternary operator you check the what it means [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)
if the value is of the **Mod** is true then it should return the value `0` if not it will return the value `1`.

coming to the next line code.
`substring()`:
**Retrieves a substring from this instance.**

```
str.Substring(x * 2, x * 2 + 2 > str.Length ? 1 : 2);
```

find more info on substring [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8)
and again I will assume the value of `x` be `4`. then the above line may look like

```
str.Substring(4 * 2, 4 * 2 + 2 > 13 ? 1 : 2); //in our case it is 13.
```

This is no difference than normal Mathematics. Above line also include the ternary operator which I mentioned above.

Hope, I was able to give you some hint on the code!.